# StarTeam: How to detach labels from a deleted folder?

Tags: starteam

I had deleted a folder/files, but forgot to detach a label before deleting the folder/files.
I delete a folder named "data", so that I can create a new folder with the same name "data".
How do I detach the label from the old folder "data"?

I tried:

1. Go to VIEW > SELECT CONFIGURATION.. to go to time where the label
   was. Now i can see both the old "data" and new "data" exist in the
   view.
2. Next I select old folder "data" and right-click on it select
   "Labels" > "Detach"
3. I select the label i wanted to detach, and click "Ok". But I got an
   error msg:

   "**Labels can only be modified from a view configuration that is current or rolled back to the label being modified.**"

Please kindly help me. Really need this. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Roll the label forward to a time after the label was created but before the files were deleted, rather than rolling the view to the label itself.

Instead of going to Labels > Detach, select the items you wish to "unlabel" and then select the Labels tab in the bottom pane.  Then, right-click on the label you wish to remove and click on Detach.